# How to open Calc from terminal and insert files?

Tags: terminal, openoffice

How to write a command to terminal in Linux that open LibreOffince Calc and inserts files in it? All files consist of one column.

Answer (score 6):

It is not clear what do you mean by "insert files in it"... May be you can give some examples.

You can open calc from commandline by

```
libreoffice --calc
```

Comment: Thank you. I mean I have file1 that consists of one column, file2 that consists of one column... and I want to insert file1, file2 to calc in a way that in column A will be file1, in column B file2...

Comment: @LukášAltman Clarifications to the question should be edits to the question itself, not left as comments to answers.

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what is the format of your original files and format of the expected output (e.g. `odf`, `sxw`, `xls`, `xlsx`, `csv`, etc.)

### Simplest case: all `csv`

Then you can use bash's `paste` command:

```
paste <(cat file1.csv) <(cat file2.csv) > out.csv
```

And then open `out.csv` in libreoffice:

```
libreoffice --calc out.csv
```

### Complicated case: `xls` or `odf` or other:

In such cases, I would recommend converting them to `csv` and use the trick as above.

```
libreoffice --convert-to csv file1.xls
libreoffice --convert-to csv file2.xls
paste <(cat file1.csv) <(cat file2.csv) > out.csv
libreoffice --calc out.csv
```

If you want your output to preserve the formatting and other properties, then you will have use other tools. Another similar tool you can try is [`oooPy`](http://ooopy.sourceforge.net/), though I must admit, I have never used it! Also not sure if it works with latest version of libreoffice.

Comment: Thank you very much. And what is wrong with this? `paste <(cat vypis.csv) <(cat sums.csv) <(cat L1R.csv) <(cat L2R.csv) <(cat L3R.csv) > out.csv` it gives error: `cs: 17: cs: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` ?

Comment: It works when I write it in terminal but is it possible to write it in file that is used like sh file in terminal?

Comment: @LukášAltman, you have be more specific and precise... give more details of exactly what you want!!! I dont know which shell you are using, but if I put this **exact** line in a script with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, it works!

Comment: `paste column1.csv column2.csv > table.csv` works as well